# How do I output one vector for a matrix or dataframe in which each element is a string concatenated from each row?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, dplyr, row

I have a matrix (or dataframe):

```
m1 <- matrix(letters[1:8], ncol = 2, byrow=TRUE)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "b" 
[2,] "c"  "d" 
[3,] "e"  "f" 
[4,] "g"  "h"
```

Desired output:

```
vec1 = c("ab", "cd", "ef", "gh")
```

I would prefer this would work for a matrix of any column or row size. Base R and dplyr appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can either convert to `data.frame` and then `paste` with `do.call`

```
do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(m1), sep=''))
#[1] "ab" "cd" "ef" "gh"
```

Or a less efficient option is `apply`

```
apply(m1, 1, paste, collapse = '')
```

---

With `tidyverse`, we can use `reduce` with `str_c`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
as_tibble(m1) %>% 
    reduce(str_c, sep="")
 #[1] "ab" "cd" "ef" "gh"
```

Or if there are only two column, extract the columns by index and use `paste0`

```
paste0(m1[,1], m1[,2])
```

---

Or with `asplit`, split the matrix by column into a `list` of `vector`s and then use `do.call`

```
do.call(paste, c(asplit(m1, 2), sep=''))
```